# Unable to play a local mp4 video on macOS Virtual Machine (running on Mac Pro host)

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware, safari, quicktime

I am unable to play a local mp4 video on macOS Virtual Machine running on Mac Pro host.

The video **doesn't** play in

1. QuickTime
2. Safari

The video **does** play in Firefox. Also, the same video plays just fine on my physical MacBook (in QuickTime and Safari).

I suspect that the issue is related to the Video Card configuration

- Total video memory **0MB**
- 3D Graphics **Disabled**

This is the vSphere configuration:
[image]

Is it related or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure how we can help. vSphere isn't running on Apple hardware, so isn't licensed, so has no real 'additions' to run on that hardware, because there are none for unlicensed hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know for sure that the VM is (eventually) running on a Mac Pro host. Everything is licensed. I am using the vSphere console to check the status of the servers but I have no permissions to configure them. Also, I've updated the question to make things clearer.

Comment: OK, then it probably comes down to being a VMWare service issue. As you can't config it, someone else is going to have to.

Comment: Find the codec used; could be something not supported by Safari or QuickTime. mediainfo is your friend: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS